# C# Panel move and resize object

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, panel, move

I have a problem with draw in panel.

I wrote a code to move and resize my object in a panel,
but when i move or resize my object you can see what happens for panel.

[image: My Application Screenshot]

And here is my code :

```
    private void DrawControlBorder(object sender)
    {
        Control control = (Control)sender;
        //define the border to be drawn, it will be offset by DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2
        //around the control, so when the drag handles are drawn they will be seem
        //connected in the middle.
        Rectangle Border = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2,
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2),
            new Size(control.Size.Width + DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE,
                control.Size.Height + DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        //define the 8 drag handles, that has the size of DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE
        Rectangle NW = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE,
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle N = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2,
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle NE = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width,
                control.Location.Y - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle W = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle E = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle SW = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle S = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width / 2 - DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE / 2,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));
        Rectangle SE = new Rectangle(
            new Point(control.Location.X + control.Width,
                control.Location.Y + control.Height),
            new Size(DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE, DRAG_HANDLE_SIZE));


        //get the form graphic
        Graphics g = panelView.CreateGraphics();

        //draw the border and drag handles
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, Border, Color.Gray, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, NW, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, N, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, NE, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, W, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, E, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, SW, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, S, true, true);
        ControlPaint.DrawGrabHandle(g, SE, true, true);

        g.Dispose();
        //graphPanel.Dispose();
        //bitmap.Dispose();
    }
```

Anybody can help me?

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do **non-persistent** drawing (which is what you are doing in your code) you need to call `graphPanel.Refresh()` **before** you do the drawing.

If you want to do **persistent** drawing you need to do it in the `Paint` event using its `e.Grpahics` parameter.

Non-persistent drawing is fine for a rubber-band display of a rectangle or a line that follows the mouse.

It will go away at any time, e.g. when minimizing/maximizing the form. So if you need the final state to persist you need to follow it up maybe in the `MouseUp` event with a call to the `Paint` event (by doing an `Invalidate()` and drawing it there..

Comment: tnx,problem solve by your guild :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you never delete what you draw.
Before redrawing new grabhandles or moving the object or whatever the conditions you would want to remove old handles, try this

```
panelView.Invalidate();
```

This function, [MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(v=vs.110).aspx), "Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control to be redrawn."

Comment: tnx,that's correct :)